# Disable WinJs.xhr Auto redirect when 302 status code is hit

Tags: redirect, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

In windows 8 metro app if i send a `winjs.xhr` (ajax) request to `http://abc.com` 
and that domain's response is auto redirect 302 to to `http://xyz.com`,

then `winjs` automatically follows the redirect and comes with the result of `xyz.com` (2nd domain), i want to stop the behavior and read the response i get from I st request before the redirect.

Comment: This might not be possible using WinJS.xhr(). Here is an article on the problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434170/Handling-HTTP-302-Responses-in-WinRT

Comment: as of now i Am using this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432892/Adventures-in-Windows-8-HTTP-Post-Helper-WinRT-Com

Answer (score 0):

WinJs.xhr is simple wrapper around XMLHttpRequest and that needs to comply with W3C standard 
(https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#infrastructure-for-the-send%28%29-method), and according to it redirects are transparent.

> If the response is an HTTP redirect:
>
> > If the origin of the URL conveyed by the Location header is same origin
> >     with the XMLHttpRequest origin and the
> >     redirect does not violate infinite
> >     loop precautions, **transparently
> >     follow the redirect** while observing
> >     the same-origin request event rules.

In Win 8.1 MS introduced `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` also available for WinJS, which has more configuration options so that might be solution for you.

Comment: Yaa myself saw windows 8.1 API few days and  planning to use "HttpClient"